# How to read/understand Bode plot of Insertion loss in EMI Filter

Tags: circuit-design, filter, emc, emi-filtering

I am designing a noise filter with a Target frequency for noise reduction =100KHz and with the help of [Murata Noise Filter Designer](https://ds.murata.co.jp/nfst/) website.

Recommended circuit from Murata with component value is as below,

[image]

But first I want to understand or read the Bode plot of a Common Mode Insertion Loss.

I have selected the followng settings in website,

- Rated Current(ldc) of L/Bead/CMCC  = 3A
- Rated Voltage(Vdc) of IWCC/CMCC = 50V
- Temperature characteristics of MLCC = 125°C
- Target frequency range for noise reduction =0.15MHz-10MHz (LWMW/SW band, etc.)

and the bode plot for Common mode Insertion loss is generated as seen below

[image]

To be frank, I have not understand this bode or how to read this.

How does this bode help to design filter for 100KHz? 
Which points in Plot are good? 
The plot is declining until 100MHz, is this good? Why is it declining? Why does it rise after 100MHz ?

I have gone through some of the available documents online. But I have not get an Idea how to read this bode plot for my use!

edit: I have added a second ciruit below with a New Bode plot. How does it differ from the First plot? Is this a good or bad while comparing with the first plot?

[image]

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The plot tells you what attenuation you can expect at a given frequency but you would need to show the complete application circuit (with a source impedance driving the filter and its load for instance). However, as the \$L\$ and \$C\$ used in this filter are associated with parasitics, they introduce undesirable poles and zeroes at high frequency and the filter attenuation suffers hence the curve going up again at some point.

Comment: Show your circuit. A bode plot without a circuit is not useful.

Comment: Andy , @VerbalKint I have added the circuit.

Comment: Your circuit is not providing any attenuation at 100 kHz. It is providing maximum attenuation at around 70 MHz.

Comment: Thanks. I have added a second circuit. Is it possible for you to compare the 2 plots? and also could you please tell me what kind of information is getting in the 2nd plot compared to the first plot. Is this a good option or bad? Do you also have any suggestion to improve?

Comment: @VerbalKint can you please have look and help?

Comment: You have to determine the amount of common-mode perturbation from your switching converter and position the filter cutoff frequency so that you pass the specifications with some margin. This is not some trivial exercise as you first need to assess common- and differential-mode signatures by measurement with a line impedance stabilization network (LISN). Once you have these values, you decide of the filter structure and its cutoff frequency so that it efficiently reduces the original signature in both DM and CM to let you pass the standard.